# Christoffel Symbols Equality Solution?

Tags: differential-geometry

They changed the exercise, so I tried to solve it again:

I have to prove the following:

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and $g$ a metric field on $\Omega$. For every $\phi \in \mathrm{Diff}(\Omega)$ let $\Xi^i_{jk}[\phi]$ be functions on $\Omega$ that transform in the same way as the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{jk}[\phi]$
$$
\Xi^i_{jk}[\phi](y) = \frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y) \Xi^r_{pq}[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y)) + \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^m} (\phi^{-1}(y)) \frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^j \partial y^k}(y).
$$
Assume that for each $y_0 \in \Omega$ there is a $\phi_0 \in \mathrm{Diff}(\Omega)$ such that $\Xi^i_{jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) = 0$ and $(\partial_a g_{bc})[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))=0$. Show $\Xi^i_{jk}[\phi] =\Gamma^i_{jk}[\phi]$ for all $\phi \in \mathrm{Diff}(\Omega)$.

---

Here is my try:

We define:

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi](y) := \Xi^i_{\,jk}[\phi](y) - \Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi](y)$

Thus we see that this transforms as a Tensor:

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi](y)= \Xi^i_{jk}[\phi](y) - \Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi](y) = \bigg(\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y) \Xi^r_{pq}[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y)) + \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^m} (\phi^{-1}(y)) \frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^j \partial y^k}(y) \bigg)- \bigg(\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y) \Gamma^r_{pq}[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y)) + \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^m} (\phi^{-1}(y)) \frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^j \partial y^k}(y)\bigg) = \frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y)  (\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y))$

Now we see that for a given pair $y_0$, $\phi_0$:

$\Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))=\frac{1}{2} g^{il}(\partial_k g_{lk} + \partial_j g_{lk} - \partial_l g_{jk})[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))= \frac{1}{2} g^{il}\left(\partial_k g_{lk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) + \partial_j g_{lk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) - \partial_l g_{jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))\right)=0$

So for $y_0$ and $\phi_0$ :

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) := \Xi^i_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) - \Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))=0$

Thus

$\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(\phi_0(y_0)) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(\phi_0(y_0))  (\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](\phi_0^{-1}(\phi_0(y_0)))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi_0^{-1}(\phi_0(y_0)))= \frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(\phi_0(y_0))\frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(\phi_0(y_0))  \left({(\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](y_0)}\right)\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(y_0)\overset{!}{=}0$

**Now my BIG question is: can I say that: Because $T^{i}_{\,jk}$ is a Tensor:**

$(\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](y_0)\overset{???}{=}0$

Because IF so then the exercise becomes trivial since:
$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi](\phi(y_0))=\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(\phi(y_0))\frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(\phi(y_0))  \overset{\underbrace{=0}}{\left({(\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](y_0)}\right)}\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(y_0)=0$

for all $\phi\in Diff(\Omega)$ and we are done

If not my old proof/idea does not hold anyway and I have got no other clue on how to overcome the problem...

Comment: I think you are asking for the proof of uniqueness of a symmetric and compatible connection on $ (M,g)$, this is standard...called Levi-Civita Connection, can be found in any textbooks on Riemannian Geometry.

Comment: I was told that too by an older student but I thought there was an easier way to show it since we have not gone through the Levi-Civita connection in our course (don't ask me why)...
You meant something like page 102 (103) of the following script? 
http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~jnatar/geometria_sem_exercicios.pdf

Comment: that [ https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=395482180546182&set=a.356358957791838.84827.341191865975214&type=1&theater ] might help

Comment: @b00nheT Well as it seems to me there may not be an easier way....in most cases proving stuffs are easier in coordinate independent form and gets too clumsy on introducing too many indices....

Comment: I don't know... it's just that using the proof you suggested it seems quite hard to me to implement the information given about the $y_0$'s and $\phi_0$'s...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally managed to get a solution which does not imply any assumption which was not given in the statement of task, does it make sense to you guys?

We define:

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi](y) := \Xi^i_{\,jk}[\phi](y) - \Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi](y)$

Thus we see that this transforms as a Tensor, hence is a Tensor:

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi](y)= \Xi^i_{jk}[\phi](y) - \Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi](y) = \bigg(\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y) \Xi^r_{pq}[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y)) + \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^m} (\phi^{-1}(y)) \frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^j \partial y^k}(y) \bigg)- \bigg(\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y) \Gamma^r_{pq}[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y)) + \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^m} (\phi^{-1}(y)) \frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^j \partial y^k}(y)\bigg) = \frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(y) \frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(y)  (\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(\phi^{-1}(y))$

Now we have that for our given $y_0$ and $\phi_0$:

$\Gamma^i_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))=\frac{1}{2} g^{il}(\partial_k g_{lk} + \partial_j g_{lk} - \partial_l g_{jk})[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))= \frac{1}{2} g^{il}\left(\partial_k g_{lk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) + \partial_j g_{lk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0)) - \partial_l g_{jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))\right)=0$

Now take any $y_0$ and any diffeomorphism $\phi\in \operatorname{Diff}(\Omega)$ :

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi(y_0))=\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(\phi(y_0))\frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(\phi(y_0))  {\left({(\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](y_0)}\right)}\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(y_0)$

By the statement of task we can always find a $\phi_0$ such that:

$T^{i}_{\,jk}[\phi_0](\phi_0(y_0))=0=\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(\phi_0(y_0))\frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(\phi_0(y_0))  {\left({(\Xi^r_{pq}-\Gamma^r_{\,pq})[\mathrm{id}](y_0)}\right)}\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^r}(y_0)$

for each $y_0\in\Omega$.

Since for any diffeomorphism we have that

$\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^j}(\phi(y))\frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^k}(\phi(y))\neq 0$

We see that the transformed part which is invariant under any $\phi\in \operatorname{Diff}(\Omega)$ is the one which maps to zero, we conclude for all of $\Omega$:

$T^i_{jk}[\phi]=\Xi^i_{jk}[\phi]-\Gamma^i_{jk}[\phi]\overset{\forall \phi}{=}0$
$$\Rightarrow \Xi^i_{jk}[\phi]=\Gamma^i_{jk}[\phi]$$

$\blacksquare$